# Relationship between linear math transformation and scaleLinear D3 function

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

I didn't understand how `scaleLinear` works.

I know it's about a linear transformation like `y = mx + b` and I use it in this way:

```js
const scale = scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 100])
```

but what are `b`, `m` and `x` in that case?

Comment: The `.domain()` declares the input value minimum and maximum, and `.range()` gives the desired output. So in your case `b` is 0 and `m` is 10.

Comment: @Pointy I don't think so because `scale(10) = 50` but `y =  10 * 10 + 0 = 100`

Comment: I get `scale(10)` = 100.

Comment: @Pointy you are right. In that case it works, but test it with `const scale = scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 150])`. `scale(2) = 30` but `y = 10 * 2 + 0 = 20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying the domain and the range, you have two points:

- *(x1,y1) = (domain[0], range[0])*
- *(x2,y2) = (domain[1], range[1])*

So *m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)*
and *b = y1 - m * x1*.

In your example from the comment:

`const scale = scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 150])`

*m = 150 / 10 = 15* and *b = 0 - 15 * 0 = 0*